# jquery- ajax post to php a null variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

**View:**

```
<table>
<tr>
<td id="percentage">Percentage:&nbsp; <?php echo $percentage; ?> %</td>
</tr>
</table>

 <div class="box-footer" style="float: right">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>student/Examinations" class="btn btn-primary" style="font-size: 20px;" id="submit">Submit</a>
    </div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var percentage = $("#percentage").text();
        console.log(percentage);                //Percentage:  28.57 %
        $("#submit").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: base_url + "student/Examinations",
                data: {percentage: percentage},
                success: function () {

                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
class Examinations extends CI_Controller {
 function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
}
 public function index() {
        $percentage = $_POST["percentage"];
        var_dump($percentage);           // var_dump null
}
}
```

MY Question: javascript variable(percentage) to pass controller , and var_dump is null why?please help me.....................................

Comment: `data: {percentage: percentage},`  should be `data: {'percentage': percentage},`

Comment: @Anant, it's not mandatory.

Comment: @vincenth var_dump is null, why?

Comment: @Anant I dont think thats right (that is to say it doesnt HAVE to be quoted): https://jsfiddle.net/1x3wq39c/

Comment: @DelightedD0D but var_dump($percentage) is null,why

Comment: @kishankakadiya are you using a framework ?

Comment: You really shouldnt be using `$_POST` in a class to begin with. It kind of flys in the face of the abstraction you get from having the class. You should really get the value in your main script and *pass it to this function* like `$ExaminationsInstance->index($_POST["percentage"])`

Comment: @DelightedD0D i used codeigniter fremwork

Comment: Im not familiar with codeigniter myself, but Id bet it's doing something that nulls out the $_POST array or handles it differently somehow, possibly to sanitize the values or something

Comment: @kishankakadiya yep, check out that duplicate question ;)

Comment: try checking if `var_dump($_POST);` has something

Comment: add `dataType: "json"` to your ajax call. You can either use firebug or the network tab by click on the link url and check the preview in the browser to see if your parameter gets pass to the controller

Comment: @ReaganGallant i used datatype:"json" ,but parameter does not pass to controller

Answer (score 0):

Not a user of code igniter myself, but using other frameworks, you better use the request object.

I quickly perused code igniter documentation, and apparently you should do something like that :

```
$percentage = $this->input->post('percentage');
```

Comment: i used $percentage = $this->input->post('percentage'); ,but var_dump ($percentage ) is null

Comment: Could you look in firebug what parameters are passed to the request ?

Comment: firebug in console.log() display Percentage:  28.57 %

Comment: but parameter does not pass

Comment: I am not talking about console log. When a ajax request is performed, it is displayed in the console, There is a tab "Post" in which you can see what has been sent. Could you check that ?

Comment: when ajax request perform and console in below post display:percentage=Percentage%3A%C2%A0+28.57+%25

Comment: percentage=Percentage%3A%C2%A0+28.57+%25

Comment: And what's the output in the "response" tab.

Comment: @ vincenth response tab is not show because when click submit button and ajax request is fast perform and dose not show reponse tab

Answer (score 0):

It behaves like that because You are doing 2 things here. It looks like that:

- You click on link with `id="submit"`
- `$(#submit).click()` is executed:

  - ajax call with parameter `percentage` is executed
  - ajax call with no handled response ends (empty function in success, so You don't even see result of Your `click` event)
- Web browser continues to act normally - it follows clicked link and goes to url: `"<?php echo base_url(); ?>student/Examinations"` with **no** `percentage` parameter

If You want to send param just modify Your href like that: `"<?php echo base_url(); ?>student/Examinations?percentage=sample_value"` and check in target script `$_GET['percentage']`

Answer (score 0):

you have not prevented execution of anchor tag, you have to prvent event of a tag

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: base_url + "student/Examinations", // or you can take $("#submit").attr('href');
            data: {percentage: $("#percentage").text()},
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```